# AWS Run Command : Python Not Found

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-systems-manager

I am using Boto3 SSM to run commands in my instance.

When I run simple command such as echo `hello world` or `mkdir abc` it works fine and gives me expected output. but when I am trying to run `python -V` or any other python command. The output is `python not found`. But python is in my EC2 Instance which is running Ubuntu. When I manually check it works fine.

Code:

```
ssm = boto3.client('ssm' ) 
commands = ['python -V']

ssm.send_command(DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript", Parameters={'commands': commands}, InstanceIds=['i-xxxxxxxxxxx'])
```

Comment: try installing python using sudo apt-get install.

Comment: I have Python in my instance. I have mentioned it already.

Comment: `boto3.client` Does this client support stream?

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/python`, rather than just `python`?

Comment: it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `python3` worked. Another thing to mention, it uses the core python in the system and does not recognise  any other version installed.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to this question depends on the OS AMI installed.

For this question there are several options to solve this problem:

- Use `python3` because `python` (python 2.x) is not installed.
- Install python 2.x (Ubuntu): `sudo apt-get install python`
- Execute the command: `sudo ln /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python` to link `python` to `python3` in the `/usr/bin` directory.

Amazon Linux 2 has Python 2.7.14 installed. The commands "python", "python2" and "python2.7" are supported. Python 3 is not installed by default.

Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit has Python 3.5.2 installed. The commands "python3" and "python3.5" are supported. Note that there is no link to "python". Python 2 is not installed by default.

One item that I noticed with Amazon Linux 2 and Python 2.7. The command `python -V` writes the version string to stderr, which will make you think that the command failed as the SSM Run Command will display the output as follows when the command actually succeeded. I discovered that the SSM Run Command is just display the stderr after the stdout separated by `----------ERROR-------`

```
----------ERROR-------
Python 2.7.14
```

Python 3 writes the version string to stdout. This took me hours to figure out as I never noticed the stderr issue with Python 2.x until today.

Information on the AMIs that I tested with.

Region: us-west-2 (Oregon)

Amazon Linux 2:
amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20180810-x86_64-gp2 (ami-6cd6f714)

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:
ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-20180814 (ami-51537029)

Answer (score 0):

boto3.ssm is not mean to be used as your quick shell injection tools. You need to install [ssm-agent to your linux instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-install-ssm-agent.html) to perform more advanced triggering, vice-versa to windows.

Comment: I did. You cannot inject anyway without that.